# Visibility Timeout for Storage queues in Azure

Tags: azure, storage

Would like to know how to set the visibility timeout for azure storage queues using azure portal. I have idea how to set the value using REST API. Suggest some solution to set the visibility time out in azure portal.

Comment: We can set the visibility timeout for a message not for the entire queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in Storage Explorer in Azure Portal at this time. You may want to use other tools like Microsoft Storage Explorer to accomplish this.